# Extracting output from PLSQL procedure to local drive of my laptop

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, extract

I have a database connection server **"server_dev"** in sqldeveloper .

Now i want to create a procedure whose output can be directly saved in a csv file for data comparison later in the local drive of my laptop.

So i tried using UTL_FILE oracle package but when i ran the procedure the UTL_FILE was trying to write in the file of the server **"server_dev"** whereas i dont have any access to that server hence that command isnt working.
for example:  the code is:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE export_to_csv_test
IS
v_file     UTL_FILE.file_type;
v_string   VARCHAR2 (4000);
CURSOR c_contexts
IS
SELECT workspace_id,context_id from contexts where rownum<5;

BEGIN
v_file :=
UTL_FILE.fopen ('Z:\My_Project_knowledge\CSVDIR', 'empdata.csv','w',1000);
FOR cur IN c_contexts

`enter code here`LOOP

v_string :=

cur.workspace_id

|| ','

|| cur.context_id;

UTL_FILE.put_line (v_file, v_string);

END LOOP;

UTL_FILE.fclose (v_file);
END;

for calling it :-
BEGIN
export_to_csv_test;
END;

Error report:
ORA-29280: invalid directory path
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
ORA-06512: at "RAY_DEV07_OWNER.EXPORT_TO_CSV_TEST", line 20
ORA-06512: at line 3
29280. 00000 -  "invalid directory path"
*Cause:    A corresponding directory object does not exist.
*Action:   Correct the directory object parameter, or create a corresponding
           directory object with the CREATE DIRECTORY command.
```

So,I analysed it and found that my SQL developer is connected to a server to my local machin and since its my office laptop I cant alter it.

Can i have any other way in which *I can save the output of my stored procedure to my local drive in a text or Csv file?*

Comment: Please post your code. Also, if you want to save something in your client machine, you may have a look at [dbms_output](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS036).

Comment: Database you're connecting to is installed sowhere remotly or on your machine?

Comment: for example:  the code is:-

Comment: PL/SQL runs inside the database. If the database server is a remote machine then it's not going to be able to hack into your laptop and write to your C: drive. You are going to need a client tool, script or application of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a file to your local machine you may use [dbms_output](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS036); for example in SQLPlus:

```
SQL> set feedback off
SQL> set echo off
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> spool d:\spool.txt
SQL> begin
  2      for i in (select level from dual connect by level <= 5) loop
  3          dbms_output.put_line('Level ' || i.level);
  4      end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /
```

WIll produce the file d:\spool.txt:

```
Level 1
Level 2
Level 3
Level 4
Level 5
```

Comment: Thanks but will this work in SQL Developer version 3.2.20.09?

Comment: For this command I am getting the spool file as:-                                                                                                               > BEGIN
  FOR i IN
  (SELECT level FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 5
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Level ' || i.level);
  END LOOP;
END;
Level 1
Level 2
Level 3
Level 4
Level 5

 how can i get only the output not the procedure ?

Comment: You may need to add [`set echo off`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-D45E2B5E-B70C-49E1-BE46-6B58DBABE220.htm#SUTIL1515)

Answer (score 0):

If you can select directly from a table or table function, then SQL*Plus 12.2's new `SET MARKUP CSV` option will be useful. Instead of paginating the query output it will produce CSV.  The full syntax is

`SET MARKUP CSV {ON|OFF} [DELIMI[TER] character] [QUOTE {ON|OFF}]`

Output generation will faster if you turn on this mode with the `sqlplus -m` option.

It's also useful for querying JSON types.  See https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/fast_generation_of_csv_and